# How to modify X-Axis of ChartingToolkit LineChart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, data-visualization

I have trouble formatting the x axis of my graph accordingly. The x axis shows values from the type DateTime. I would like to control which information is displayed on the x axis. For example only Seconds and Milliseconds. In addition I would like to set an interval for the x axis, if there are too many values to display.

Here is my current state:

I am using the chartingToolkit with following reference, to display a LineChart with two lines:

```
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

The data input for the graph look like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>>> ListOutputGraph { get; set; }
```

This observable collection contains a list for each of the lines to be displayed

Now I plot the graph via XAML like this:

```
                <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="LineChart1" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-30,0,0" Height="382">

                    <!-- Line P -->
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="P" Title="P Out" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" >
                        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:DataPoint">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                                            <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="1">
                                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                                    <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                                        <ContentControl Content="Data Row: P" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}"  ContentStringFormat="Time:     {0}" />
                                                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DependentValue}" ContentStringFormat="Value:    {0}"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                                <Ellipse StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>

                    <!-- Line L -->
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="L" Title="L Out"  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" >
                        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:DataPoint">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                                            <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="1">
                                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                                    <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                                        <ContentControl Content="Data Row: L" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}"  ContentStringFormat="Time:      {0}" />
                                                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DependentValue}" ContentStringFormat="Value:     {0}"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                                <Ellipse StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

---

The result currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Just to have an idea: what is the result you would like to obtain?

Comment: @IlVic I would like to display Seconds and milliseconds of my DateTime in the X-Axis. In addition I thought about to rotate the Seconds/Milliseconds vertically and the values shall be displayed in an interval